# Assigning random numbers to column of names in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to do a tournament shuffling. For example i have 15 players and i'd like to create a play-off table.

So my idea would work in a way that i'd write all the players in the column, let's say it's column B. Then the so called macro will draft a number for every player in range 1-playerCount (one number for one player). After that the players are assigned in the playoff table (which is really easy to do in Excel with borderlines).

In coding manner it could work in a way that every person in a column gets drafted a number. The numbers are in a list. So let's say we have 15 players, at first there are numbers 1-15 in a list. Then a list gets shuffled (basically same as drafting a random number but we don't have to start searching for unassigned numbers). First element (or last, doesen't matter) will be assigned for the player. So now players all get random numbers which will draft them into the table. These numbers 1-15 could represent the column X maybe, where the names should go into and then the values in this column change.

My question is - how hard would it be to implement this kind of thing? As a Java Programmer i watch this idea and i'd think that doing something in JAVA it shouldn't take long and would be pretty easy. The problem with JAVA is that then the UI needs to be coded and creating UI which makes playoff tables isn't the easiest solution.

Comment: It looks like you have a pretty good plan and shouldn't be too hard to implement with some research and gumption.  Probably should start with google.  Do a bit of research on the randbetween function.  Once you have that down, do a bit more googling on functions or subs that will return only unused numbers (or something to that effect).  After that, give it a go and post back if you get stuck.  Be sure to post what you tried, what didn't work, and what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for an infinite number of people. Note that the more people you add, the longer the code will run, because it has to check everything over and over again.

```
Private Sub numb_ass()
Dim i As Integer: i = 1
Dim v As Integer
Dim lr As Integer
Dim t As Integer: t = 1

With ActiveSheet
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Do Until i > lr
NewNumber:
    v = Int(lr * Rnd() + 1)
    Do Until t > lr
        If v = Range("B" & t) Then
            If t > lr Then: Exit Sub
            t = 1
            GoTo NewNumber
        End If
        t = t + 1
        If t > lr Then: Range("B" & i) = v
    Loop
t = 1
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the thing i wanted

Comment: Just a few follow up questions - is it normal for it to crash if i've already ran it once and haven't deleted the empty space in result column (B)? Second question, how could i modify that the count begins from the second row instead of first one?

Comment: As for first question, i think this could be avoided if the program checks at first whether the area where the randomed numbers will appear (column B) is empty or not and then clear it at first.

Comment: It should not crash. It just calculates everything again, but always finds a value. This could take a long time, but should not crash. You could counter this by adding `If IsNull(Range("B" & i) ) Then` at the beginning of the loop. For your second question, change the value of `i` and `t` to the desired row. (2)

Comment: It does get stuck in an infinite loop, when all numbers have been used and it's still not at the end. But this will definitely put you in the right direction.

Comment: I fixed it using .Columns(2).ClearContents in With ActiveSheet.

Comment: changing i and t to two didn't work. I have 13 elements and in the top description "NAME". It still counts the whole column

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Record Macro if you wish first. Say names are in ColumnB, 1>15 in ColumnC (both starting in Row1). In A1 and copied down to A15 enter:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,1000)
```

the sort ColumnA:B on A.

Comment: This could work, but it starts to re-use numbers which are already used. For example player F and player B could both be assigned with number 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to use sorting, you can also do it like this:

```
        A           B                  C
1  Player Name |  Rand   |       Player Number
  ============+======+==============================
2  John        | =Rand() | =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6,">"&B2)
3  James       | =Rand() | =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6,">"&B3)
4  Jim         | =Rand() | =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6,">"&B4)
5  George      | =Rand() | =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6,">"&B5)
6  Pete        | =Rand() | =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6,">"&B6)
```

How does it work? Everytime the sheet is changed/refreshed a new random number is generated in column B. Column C merely counts how many numbers in that row are greater than the remaining values in column B.

The chance for the `Rand()` values to be exactly the same is minimal, so you shouldn't worry about players having the same nubmer.

Comment: Are they still minimal if i use for example 64 players?

Comment: I would say so, the number generated by Rand looks like this '0.537072112173298', so I think it's pretty safe. But @pnuts has a point, this is not practical as the Rand changes on every change on the worksheet, I meant that only as a proof of concept. If you get VBA to handle your Rand() generation, it would be better of course.